# c# webbrowser Form Drawing Rectangle

Tags: c#, browser

My question may sound stupid but I wonder if I can draw a rectangle over my webbrowser object and move that constant sized rectangle over my webbrowser?

I have tried to draw a rectangle but rectangle does not visible on my form and webbrowser.

I dont know what is wrong with it.

```
Graphics g = webBrowser1.CreateGraphics();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(400,400, 200, 100);
using (Pen pen = new Pen (Color.Red, 2)
{
 g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
}
```

this is the code..I just tried to draw a rectangle first than to deal with mouse thing but I was not successful at drawing.

**However, I have noticed that the rectangle is actually existing but it is under the WebBrowser object. I need my rectangle to be on top of the WebBrowser.**

How can I **bring the Rectangle on to the top of my WebBrowser** so it can be visible?

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code showing us what you tried / are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Graphics g = webBrowser1.CreateGraphics();
```

with

```
Graphics g = Form1.CreateGraphics();
```

Assuming `Form1` is the name of your form.

Comment: I tried to change it to Form1 but not successful. there is not method for CreateGraphics for Form1.

Comment: I noticed my mistake! The rectangle is drawn on the Form Canvas. However, there is a WebBrowser over my Form and for that reason the rectangle is staying under the WebBrowser. Now the question is how to bring that rectangle to the front on to the WebBrowser?